# MythBuntu blank screen

Tags: ati, mythbuntu

Installed MythBuntu on PC with ATI Radeon 7500 graphics card (uses RV200 I believe). The installation completed without any problems, but when I then rebooted, after the POST there was a brief flash on the screen but which then stayed blank/black although the monitor obviously thinks there is a signal as it doesn't go to sleep.

This is not just in X as even if I try to switch to a different screen which should show a login prompt, it just stays blank. In fact it's almost as if the keyboard isn't working, but that seems less likely. With no video actually being sent, it's impossible to see even if it does switch screens.

I can `ssh` in from a different machine, so it is all running and tried this:-

`lshw -c video` starts with:-

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
```

so no driver has loaded for this card - hence no output I guess.

```
dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon' ->

[ 25.622611] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810<br>
[ 26.591861] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.<br>
[ 26.653361] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV200 0x1002:0x5157 0x1002:0x013A).<br>
[ 26.653420] [drm] register mmio base: 0xEF000000<br>
[ 26.653425] [drm] register mmio size: 65536<br>
[ 26.653975] radeon 0000:01:00.0: putting AGP V2 device into 4x mode<br>
[ 26.653985] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 64M 0x00000000 - 0x03FFFFFF<br>
[ 26.654000] radeon 0000:01:00.0: limiting VRAM to PCI aperture size<br>
[ 26.654008] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 0M 0x0000000000000000 - 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (0M used)<br>
[ 26.654083] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=0M, BAR=0M<br>
[ 26.654089] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR<br>
[ 26.662225] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Fatal error during GPU init<br>
[ 26.662242] [drm] radeon: finishing device.<br>
[ 26.662257] [drm] radeon: cp finalized<br>
[ 26.662468] [drm] radeon: ttm finalized<br>
[ 26.669999] radeon: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -12<br>
```

which rather looks like there was a problem when trying to load the driver, hence the card remains 'UNCLAIMED'.

Anyone suggest what this problem is? The card does work, until the system has booted then there is NO video output whatsoever. It appears the failure to load the driver has killed it completely.

Er, help!